# How To Self-Invoke a beans method in OSGI

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

```
Class MyTestBean {
    public void requiredMethod(){
         //somehow call the "requiresNewMethod" with a new transaction
         //provided from the container
         this.requiresNewMethod(); //this does not work.. no new transaction is created            
     }

    public void requiresNewMethod(){ //code..}
}
```

Blueprint xml :

```
  <bean id="myTestBean "
    class="MyTestBean ">
    <jpa:context property="entityManager" unitname="sample" />
    <tx:transaction method="requiredMethod" value="Required" />
    <tx:transaction method="requiresNewMethod" value="RequiresNew" />
  </bean>
```

When the requiredMethod is called the JPA manager creates a new transaction (if it is not already in a transaction). I would like to call the method "requiresNewMethod" from inside the "requiredMethod" and force the JPA manager to create a new (nested) transaction.

For example if the above were EJB and I was in a EJB container i could do that

```
public void requiredMethod(){
    sessionContext.getBusinessObject(MyTestBean.class).requiresNewMethod();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to inject your own bean into a property of MyTestBean and access it that way.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I would like a cleaner solution. I don' t like having that kind of cycle reference inside the bean. I will try your proposal to see if this works and i will use it as a last resort solution. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out injecting the bean into the bean itself as a property and then invoking the desired methods through the injected bean does not work, Behaves the same as calling directly the method. In the other hand if i create a new bean and inject , works as charm.. but creating a new bean is not what i wanted. Thanks